# findingoptimal weights in cross-entropy loss function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand how cross-entropy works for finding the optimal weights in neural networks in a classic way. I use cross-entropy as a loss function and try to find the derivative of cross-entropy with respect to $w _ (pq) $ and then makes the result of derivative equal to zero. but all papers I read before used gradient descent for optimizing function and I can't find any other way. 
cause in most cases, the equation $∇f=0$ cannot be solved symbolically but I work with an online network which means I can't use gradient descent so I try to find optimal weights using classic way. here is the cost function:

$$j=-\sum_{i=1} ^t net_{c_i}^i + \sum_{i=1}^t log \sum_{c'=1}^ c e^{net_{c'}^i}$$

where ${net_{c'}^i}$ is:

$${net_{c'}^i}= \sum_{k=1}^k w_{c'k}h_k^i$$

$i=1$ to $N$ is the stream of data samples and as long as we have online learning just t number of these samples come to network.

the Derivative of $j$ function is equal to:

$$\frac{\partial j}{\partial w_{pq}} = -\sum_{i\in p}h_g^i + \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{h_q^i e^ {\sum_{k=1}^kw_{pk}h_k^i}}{\sum_{c'=1}^c e ^{\sum_{k=1}^kw_{c'k}h_k^i}}=0$$

I need to find the roots of this function but the function seems too hard to find so here is my question is there any way or approximation to find roots?

Comment: You can use double dollar signs to get displayed equations (which are a lot easier to read with all those indices). You can also use commands like `\log` to avoid italicizing the names of operators, and for operators without such a special command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.